# Set static hostname app service console Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have some app services and processes in the back that the target it's the machine name (hostname) where the app service it's hosted. I realized that when I go to the console in the service app, the hostname keeps changing for some reason.

I would like to know if there is a way to set a static hostname.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you send a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The machine name changes because you have multipul instances(machine) of your webapp. If you have only one instance, the machine name will not change.

[image]

If you want to keep multiple instances, you can disable the ARR affinity feature of the webapp.

[image]

Reference:

[Disable Session affinity cookie (ARR cookie) for Azure web apps](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2016/05/16/Disable-Session-affinity-cookie-(ARR-cookie)-for-Azure-web-apps.html)

Comment: Yeah we were using multiple instances and that was the issue. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you running on multiple instances? (Check Scale-out blade of the WebApp). When you try to access the Kudu site, it can go to the Kudu of any of these instances. Which is why you'd see the hostname changing. You can go to a specific instance using ARR Affinity cookie, but you wouldn't have control over the hostname itself.

Comment: Yeah, we were using multiple instances that was the issue. We found a workaround for the script in the code.